# Dynamic SPQuery

Tags: sharepoint, spquery

I want to discuss a scenario here: I want to build a search criteria by using dynamic SPQuery. On my application page, I have 2 textboxes, 2 comboboxes and a people picker Control. Depending on users, which Control's values they use to view the results in the grid. May be they put/select values from some or all of the Controls for searching. I cound not find an efficient way to build this dynamic Query. I need good examples or suggestions to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try http://sharepointcamlhelper.codeplex.com/ it is dynamic sp query builder